# elasticsearch/kiabana - analyze and visualize total time for transactions?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Parsing log files using logstash, here is the json sent to elasticsearch looks like:

For log lines contaning transaction start time, i add db_transaction_commit_begin_time field with the time it is logged.

```
{
                           "message" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048  INFO [T:3 ID:26] (ClassName.java:396) - End committing transaction",
                          "@version" => "1",
                        "@timestamp" => "2015-05-27T15:24:11.594Z",
                              "host" => "test.com",
                              "path" => "/abc/xyz/log.logstash.test",
                "logTimestampString" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048",
                          "logLevel" => "INFO",
                        "threadInfo" => "T:3 ID:26",
                             "class" => "ClassName.java",
                              "line" => "396",
                        "logMessage" => "End committing transaction",
    "db_transaction_commit_begin_time" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048"
}
```

For log lines contaning transaction end time, i add db_transaction_commit_end_time field with the time it is logged.

```
{
                           "message" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048  INFO [T:3 ID:26] (ClassName.java:396) - End committing transaction",
                          "@version" => "1",
                        "@timestamp" => "2015-05-27T15:24:11.594Z",
                              "host" => "test.com",
                              "path" => "/abc/xyz/log.logstash.test",
                "logTimestampString" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048",
                          "logLevel" => "INFO",
                        "threadInfo" => "T:3 ID:26",
                             "class" => "ClassName.java",
                              "line" => "396",
                        "logMessage" => "End committing transaction",
    "db_transaction_commit_end_time" => "2015-05-27 10:26:47,048"
}
```

Is it possible to calculate time for db transaction (db_transaction_commit_end_time - db_transaction_commit_begin_time) where threadinfo is same ?. I know aggregation might help but I am new and couldn't figure it out.

If somehow I get the db_transaction_time calculated and stored in a variable. how can I visualize time taken in a kibana chart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [elapsed{}](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) filter in logstash.